# how can I have wildcard subdomain in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wildcard-subdomain

I want to have dynamic wiladcard subdomain in my project.I want each provider have special subdomain. e.g provider1.mydomain.com change to mydomain.com/provider1
and I want pass provider1 as parameter to my action.

```
public ActionResult Details(string provider1){
   //there is some code for show provider details     
   return view();
   }
```

How can I do this in my project and How can I do this in localhost?

Comment: Use Google to learn IIS wildcard domain name support and URL Rewrite module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to RouteConfig in App_start Folder :

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.Add(new SubdomainRoute());
    }
```